# Is it possible to list VIEWS being used inside another VIEW?

Tags: sql-server

In SQLServer, I am able to list the tables used by a VIEW with  `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE`.  But some of my VIEWS use just other VIEWS.  Is there a way to get that list of VIEW names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities` to find all references, then join back to `sys.views` to get the child view names

```sql
SELECT
  r.referenced_entity_name,
  r.referenced_minor_name,
  v2.name
FROM sys.views v
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = v.schema_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(s.name + '.' + v.name, 'OBJECT') r
JOIN sys.views v2 ON v2.object_id = r.referenced_id;
```

If you were looking only for views which *only* refer to other views, you can do something like this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
      r.referenced_entity_name,
      r.referenced_minor_name,
      v2.name,
      nonViews = COUNT(CASE WHEN o2.type IN ('FT','IF','U','TF') THEN 1 END)
                   OVER (PARTITION BY v.object_id)
    FROM sys.views v
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = v.schema_id
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(s.name + '.' + v.name, 'OBJECT') r
    JOIN sys.objects o2 ON o2.object_id = r.referenced_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.views v2 ON v2.object_id = r.referenced_id
) v
WHERE nonViews = 0;
```

Generally you should avoid `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`, it's only for compatibility.